# Transforming an English Sentence Into Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> "Not Everybody likes everybody."

I have the problem that everybody is both the subject and object of that sentence.

I am not sure if that is correct: $\exists x \ \lnot \text l(x, x)$,

where x = everybody and $\text l(x, x) =$ "x likes x".

UPDATE 1: Second attempt

$\lnot \forall y \in x \ \forall z \in x \ \text l(y,z)$

UPDATE 2:
There exists some person y that does not like every z:

$\exists y \ \lnot \forall z \ \text l(y,z)$

Comment: I'd define l(x,y) as x likes y, but otherwise this is correct.

Comment: "everybody likes everybody" is "for all people x, for all people y, x likes y:. Now negate that.un English first. It begins "there is some person x ..."

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with user458276’s comment. You can’t say what $x$ is at the same time you use it as the variable for $\exists$. The variable after $\exists$ is “bound” and represents a particular but arbitrary element of a set (which you didn’t identify). For $x$ to take on a specific value, it must be “free” and able to be substituted with a value. You are also avoiding dealing with what “everybody” means by trying to let it be the value of a variable. If you had to write “Everybody likes cheese.” in propositional logic, would you let $C(x)$ mean “$x$ likes cheese” and write the sentence as $C(everybody)$?

Comment: I made an update to my question inspired by your comment.

Comment: Your update is good! Note: You could also move the $\lnot$ through the $\forall$ to get a version with only $\exists$, and it would also be helpful to specify the set (of all people) that is the domain of quantification here.